# user added to text field and updated rather than added user again after update JavaScript

Tags: javascript, updating

In my application i have a viewing screen and a commentary screen. 
In the viewing screen it display a message feed and a score feed like this:

Message Feed:
Chelsea Vs Arsenal (1) - (0): Hazard scores!!!

and the score feed like this:
Chelsea Vs Arsenal (1) - (0)

However if i update the score it creates a new score like so:
Chelsea Vs Arsenal (1) - (0)
Chelsea Vs Arsenal (1) - (1)

I would rather keep this as one score and only update just the number within it how would i go about doing this in JavaScript.

Code as follows:

This increases the goal

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#incrementHomeScore").click(function () {
                var n = $("#homeGoal");
                n.val(Number(n.val()) + 1);
            });
            $("#incrementAwayScore").click(function () {
                var n = $("#awayGoal");
                n.val(Number(n.val()) + 1);
            });
        });
```

This adds the message to the feed

```
    function AddMessage(goal, teamNames, updates) {

        $('#divChatWindow').append('<div class="message"><span class="userName">' + teamNames + goal + '</span>: ' + updates + '</div>');
        $('#divUsersViewing').append('<div class=message"><span class="userName">' + teamNames + goal + '</span>: ' + updates + '</div>');
        $('#divViewScores').append('<div class=user>' + teamNames + goal + '</span></div>');
        var height = $('#divChatWindow')[0].scrollHeight;
        var height_ = $('#divUsersViewing')[0].scrollHeight;
        $('#divChatWindow').scrollTop(height);
    }
```

thanks